# Преобразовние списка

Tags: python, list

Как преобразовать `a = array([1921, 1922, 1924])` в `b = [1921, 1922, 1924]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

просто превратите в список

```
b = list(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

Если `array` - это numpy.ndarray, то можно воспользоваться методом [ndarray.tolist()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
b = a.tolist()
```

результат:

```
In [246]: b
Out[246]: [1921, 1922, 1924]
```

---

**UPD:** в отличие от использования `list(arr)`, `arr.tolist()` будет ожидаемо работать для двухмерных и более матриц:

```
In [247]: a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

In [248]: a
Out[248]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [249]: list(a)
Out[249]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5])]

In [250]: a.tolist()
Out[250]: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```